# Youtube GIF thumbnail

Tags: youtube

I want to ask please if anyone knows how to work with the GIF previews.
What I mean is the GIFs you see in the channel itself and not in preview on the main page.

1. I have a few videos on my channel in which some have the GIF preview and some don't
   How does this work? Why some have a GIF and some don't?
2. YouTube is choosing a snip by its own and for the last video I uploaded it took the worst snip from an almost 2h clip and it's very frustrating.
   How can I change it?

Thanks.

The documentation says I can upload 2mb GIF with 1280x720 but I get the message that it's not a picture.
I tried uploading the video again but the same snip was selected.